# WIX make a small update

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have WIX project with about 100 files and 20 mb total size for product. I have fund a bug and want to create a new .MSI file that consists only one or two changed files.

How I can do it? How should my project XML looks like? Should it contains only changed files and remove all other files and components?

Comment: most problem was with this command - torch -p -xi .\output\%VER_OLD%\project.wixpdb .\output\%VER_NEW%\rproject.wixpdb  -out .\output\%VER_OLD%_to_%VER_NEW%\diff.wixmst during creating patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a patch - "small update" is something a little different.  If you're using WiX v3 then you can use the torch and pyro utilities to create a patch:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm

Comment: I have reread this article and get the idea. Now I am looking of how organize build process so it produce the current installation an the patch since previous version